# How to make my default JDK FX-enabled?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

As I've tried to create a Java FX 2.0 application project in NetBeans IDE 7.1 Beta, it said I have no FX-enabled JDK. I've managed to set up an "FX-enabled JDK" folowing the instructions on how to create it manually (found [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html#create-platform)). But I neither need nor want to have multiple JDKs, I want the one and only to be "FX-enabled". Though, the default JDK NetBeans platform entry (referencing the very same JDK installation actually) even does not contain a Java FX tab in its settings. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in NB 7.1 Beta you can't have default JDK being FX enabled.

All new JavaFX projects will refer to Java Platfrom named "Default JFX Platform".

Comment: It actually required the name Default_JavaFX_Platform but cheers for the intuition :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download and install the JavaFX 2.0 SDK from javafx.com, and it will work.
It doesn't need any other JDK. It installs next to your already installed JDK.

After you have installed the JavaFX SDK you can create a new JavaFX application, and everything will be great.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe I was to install JavaFX to the same directory where I've installed JDK before?

Comment: No you dont need to change the default. Do you use JDK 7 or 6? And is it 32 or 64 bit version? Because if I remember right, JavaFX likes JDK 6 32 bit.

Comment: I use JDK 7 32-bit, and I always change the default installation path as I hate installing it into "Program Files" (especially for the space in its name, I used to have problems with this).